# Excel Formula to count first occurrence of '/' from right side of the string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I looking for a excel function that can extract all the string before last occurrence of '/'

sample:

```
http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product/NAM_MASTERDATA
```

Expected output:

```
http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product
```

I able to achieved this by using below excel formula. But this logic was assumed '/' occurrence was at position 5. I looking a more flexible formula where the formula should count first occurrence of '/' from right side of the string. Appreciate any help on this

`=MID(A1,1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",5))-1)`

Comment: You might need VBA or a user defined function to handle this in the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-1)
```

It will find the last "/" by comparing the length of the string with and without the "/".
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `AGGREGATE`; first finds the position of the last "/" then truncates left:

```
=LEFT(A1, AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:$200)/(MID(A1,ROW($1:$200),1)="/"),1)-1)
```

`200` stands for any upperbound on the position of the last `"/"`.

To make the array's size adapt automatically to the length of the string in `A1`, it's a bit longer formula but very fast:

```
=LEFT(A1, AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(OFFSET($A1,0,0,LEN(A1)))/
  (MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A1,0,0,LEN(A1))),1)="/"),1)-1)
```